# A system of nonlinear generalized Abel's integral equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, integral-equations

How can solve the following system of nonlinear generalized Abel's integral equation:

$\begin{cases} u(x)-2v(x)+\int_0^x ‎\frac{u^2 (t)+v^2 (t)}{(x-t)^{‎\frac{1}{5}‎}}\; ‎dt=g_1 ‎(x), ‎\\‎
v(x)-u(x)-\int_0^x ‎‎\frac{u(t)v(t)}{(x-t)^{‎\frac{1}{3}‎}}\; ‎dt=g_2 ‎(x) \end{cases}‎$
where

$\begin{cases} ‎g_1 (x)&=x^2 -2x^3 +‎\frac{390625}{1573656}x^{‎\frac{34}{5}‎}+‎\frac{3125}{9576}‎‎x^{‎\frac{24}{5}‎},\\
g_2 (x)&=x^3 -x^2 -‎\frac{2187}{5236}‎x^{‎\frac{17}{3}‎} \end{cases}$

with $0‎\leq ‎x‎\leq ‎1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system in question is solved this article:
*A new operational method to solve Abel’s and generalized Abel’s integral equations*. [see here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319910584_A_new_operational_method_to_solve_Abel's_and_generalized_Abel's_integral_equations)